# How to get value from dynamic button

Tags: vb.net

I created a dynamic button inside Vb.Net code with this

```
 Private Sub getreport()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("Connectionstring").ConnectionString()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
                'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [UserName],[ReportName] FROM [BizView_Dev2].[dbo].[ReportPrivilege]  where username =  '" & Session("UAuthen") & "'"
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from report"
                cmd.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        Dim BtnRepName = New Button
                        BtnRepName.Style.Add("text-align", "center")
                        BtnRepName.Style.Add("verticle-align", "middle")
                        BtnRepName.Style.Add("display", "table-cell")
                        BtnRepName.Style.Add("margin", "17px")
                        BtnRepName.Style.Add("border-radius", "0%")
                        BtnRepName.CssClass = "btn  btn-lg btn-scb "
                        BtnRepName.Width = 300
                        BtnRepName.Height = 100
                        AddHandler BtnRepName.Click, AddressOf BtnRepName_Click
                        BtnRepName.Text = sdr("rep_name").ToString()
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(BtnRepName)

                    End While
                End Using
                conn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

but I don't know how to get value from each button when I Click on  button will get a value from each button if I click a button that generated to "TReport" then it's will show Treport in textbox like this

```
Private Sub BtnRepName_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  txtrep.text = BtnRepName.text 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the "sender" as button then get the value of the text.

```
Dim senderButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
textrep.text = senderButton.Text
```

Comment: on sub BtnREpname_Click